# Establishing Transition Counts in R

Tags: r

I have a data that looks like this

| PTNUM | STATE | AGE | WAVE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 1 | 17 | 1 |
| 12345 | 1 | 20 | 2 |
| 12345 | 2 | 26 | 3 |
| 12345 | 3 | 31 | 4 |
| 12345 | 2 | 37 | 5 |
| 12346 | 1 | 15 | 1 |
| 12346 | 1 | 23 | 2 |
| 12346 | 1 | 28 | 3 |
| 12346 | 1 | 33 | 4 |
| 12346 | 1 | 41 | 5 |
| 12347 | 1 | 19 | 1 |
| 12347 | 2 | 23 | 2 |
| 12347 | 2 | 29 | 3 |
| 12347 | 3 | 32 | 4 |
| 12347 | 3 | 39 | 5 |
| 12348 | 1 | 17 | 1 |
| 12348 | 2 | 22 | 2 |
| 12348 | 3 | 29 | 3 |
| 12348 | 2 | 31 | 4 |
| 12348 | 3 | 40 | 5 |
| 12349 | 1 | 12 | 1 |
| 12349 | 2 | 19 | 2 |
| 12349 | 2 | 24 | 3 |
| 12349 | 2 | 30 | 4 |
| 12349 | 3 | 36 | 5 |

I would like to establish the transition of states from 1 to 2, 2 to 3 and 3 to 2 i.e., the age they are at 1 and and the age when they move to 2 similarly for other transitions and have them in a table for each individual. how can this be done?

expected output:

| PTNUM | 1-2 | 2-3 | 3-2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | (20,26) | (26,31) | (31,37) |
| 12346 | NA | NA | NA |
| 12347 | (19,23) | (29,32) | NA |
| 12348 | (17,22) | (22,29) | (29,31) |
| 12349 | (12,19) | (30,36) | NA |

help is much appreciated.

Comment: Added the expected output to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(PTNUM) %>% 
  mutate(AGE12 = case_when(STATE == 1 & lead(STATE) == 2| 
     STATE == 2 & lag(STATE) == 1 ~ AGE), 
     AGE23 =case_when(STATE == 2 & lead(STATE) == 3| STATE == 3 &
        lag(STATE) == 2 ~ AGE), 
    AGE32 =case_when(STATE == 3 & lead(STATE) == 2| STATE == 2 &
      lag(STATE) == 3 ~ AGE) ) %>% 
   summarise(across(matches("AGE\\d+"),
    ~ if(all(is.na(.x))) NA else sprintf("(%s)", 
    toString(na.omit(.x)))), .groups = 'drop')
```